# Pass a function with a set argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handleChange that takes an index and value.  I want to pass it to a component but I don't want to pass in the index as a prop. I'm trying to return a function that has index already set but not sure how. I tried using bind?

```
handleChange(index, value) {}

[1,2,3].map((item,index) => 
  <component onChange={()=> index => handleChange.bind(this, index)} />
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close:

```
[1,2,3].map((item,index) => 
  <component onChange={handleChange.bind(this, index)} />
)
```

Breaking down what you had before in your `{}`, you were passing a function that returns a function instead of just passing a direct function, which `.bind(...)` creates for you. An alternative that is cleaner looking, IMO, but does almost the same thing would be:

```
[1,2,3].map((item,index) => 
  <component onChange={value => handleChange(index, value)} />
)
```